# ssh-agent not working properly

Tags: debian, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm currently trying to get `ssh-agent` to work.
No matter what I'm doing, I just can't get the around the password prompt.

For testing I even tried connecting to localhost:

- `ssh-keygen` to generate the `id_rsa`
- `ssh-add id_rsa` in the .ssh folder
- `ssh-add -l` shows the correct fingerprint
- `ssh user@localhost` still asks me for a password
- `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` shows the process running

Is there something else I need to configure before using the ssh-agent?
I tried it with several machines and users, as well as RSA and DSA keys.

I'm using Debian 7 btw.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint, where my problem might be.

Comment: Did you add the public key to `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: On the host or remote machine?

Comment: On the remote machine, of course. Do you understand how these files work? `authorized_keys` is the list of client keys that are allowed to login to the account, so it has to be on the server.

Comment: But this makes the ssh-agent unnecessary right?

Comment: They have nothing to do with each other. `ssh-agent` is how you save the password for the private key file on the local machine. `authorized_keys` tells the remote machine which private keys to allow to login.

Comment: The public-key goes in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the user you with to login as on the remote machine(s). The `ssh-agent`, looks after you private-key on the local machine. So that you don't have to keep re-entering the pass-phrase (not pass word) to unlock it. If you do not involve the remote machine (by putting your public key onto it) then it could not work. If it did, then one could create a key and get in anywhere.

Comment: Just like Sato Katsura's answer your answer was of course also correct. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generated a `ssh` key.  That alone doesn't enable public key authentication, you also need to add the public key to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine, to the account you want to log to.  The easy way to do that is with `ssh-copy-id`:

```
ssh-copy-id hostname
```

or

```
ssh-copy-id username@hostname
```

if the username on the remote host is different from the one on the current machine.  This will ask for your password on the remote machine.

Comment: If i add my ssh key to the remote machines authorized_keys, what does the ssh-agent do? My understanding was, that the ssh-agent stores the remote machines password and fills the password prompt when needed. So no manipulation on the remote machine is necessary.

Comment: `ssh-agent` holds in memory the key on the _local_ machine.  This makes a difference if you generated your key with a password: without `ssh-agent` you'll be asked for the key's password every time you run `ssh`, with `ssh-agent` you'll only be asked for said password on the first run in the current session.

Comment: What should happen if i use ssh-keygen without a password? I did this and yet i still have to type the ssh password on every connection attempt. Is this correct ?

Comment: Nope.  If your key doesn't have a password and you're still asked for one when you run `ssh` you haven't succeeded to enable public key authentication, and you're asked for your password on the remote machine (not the key's password).  You can add option `-v` to `ssh` to find out if public key is used or not.  Please note that you can't login without passwords with no manipulation on the remote machine (it would be a security problem if you could).

Comment: I will look into the -v option later, this could give me a hint whats going wrong.

Comment: @SatoKatsura is meaning the private-keys **pass-phrase**; this is not the same as the remote accounts pass-word. The pass-phrase is used to encrypt the private-key, it is used locally to get the private-key from the encrypted file. Do not use the same pass-phrase and pass-word. Pass-phrases should be less guessable than pass-words. Pass-words should be less guessable than you think.

Comment: Hello, I had some time to test your suggestions and your initial answer was answer was correct! I had to add the remote machines public_key to the authorized_keys file. Then i can connect from the host using the related private key. In addition ssh -v told that it was trying to use public key authentication.

Comment: I was not really aware of the correct use of private and public keys until now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the correct permissions on the .ssh and .ssh/authorized_keys folder/file? Strict permissions may be required depending on your SSH server config. Also be sure ownership is correct.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```